# How can I execute an `INSERT INTO` on a table with a string primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, oauth-2.0, postgresql-9.1

I have two tables that are initialized with something like this:

```
create table foo ( 
     "id" varchar(254) not null primary key, 
     "first_name" varchar(254) not null);

create table my_user (
     "id" serial not null primary key, 
     "role" varchar(254) not null,
     "first_name" varchar(254) not null);
```

The reason why the `id` column of `foo` is a varchar(254) instead of a serial is because in normal operations I'm inserting in an id provided by Google OAuth2 instead of generating my own id values.

I now have a set of records in a third table I call `temp` with the `first_name` column. I'm trying to emulate [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6898775/1708136), but I'm not sure how to do so for string primary keys.

```
select * from (insert into my_user(id, role) 
    ('some id value I want to generate, like historical || incrementing number',
    [a fixed number],
    select first_name from temp) returning id);
```

As it says in the [official Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-insert.html), I know I need to get the arguments following the insert statement into the format of a table that matches the declaration of `my_user`. I guess I'm just lost as to how to generate a column of the ids I want here, or even a column of one number repeating.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Stongly advise to make the PK a plain integer (possibly serial) and use that as a FK.  Treat the OAUTH2 string as an alternate key (just add a UNIQUE constraint on it)

Comment: Yeah, I ended up taking your advice @wildplasser Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could insert a UUID (it's like a GUID) in your ID... It's guaranteed to be unique.

Sadly it's a little complex to load the module: [Generating a UUID in Postgres for Insert statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505158/generating-a-uuid-in-postgres-for-insert-statement)

Ah... and what wildplasser said, +1! :-)

Comment: With 9.1+ as is the case just do `create extension`.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto You still need administrative privileges, and must remember to do it on each server you use. If you work in a big enterprise, just thinking of doing it could be a nightmare. Compare it with SQL Server: `NEWID()`, no permissions to ask, no bureaucracy to fulfill.