# Is INSERT ... SELECT an atomic transaction?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, locking, upsert

I use a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO table
     SELECT * FROM table2 t2
        JOIN ...
        ...
        WHERE table2.date < now() - '1 day'::INTERVAL
     FOR UPDATE OF t2 SKIP LOCKED
ON CONFLICT (...)
    DO UPDATE SET ...
RETURNING *;
```

My question is about `FOR UPDATE t2 SKIP LOCKED`. Should I use it here? Or will Postgres lock these rows automatically with `INSERT SELECT ON CONFLICT` till the end of the transaction?

My goal is to prevent other apps from (concurrently) capturing rows with the inner `SELECT` which are already captured by this one.

Comment: There is no reason to automatically lock rows from a subquery in `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` because the subuery is executed once. You should lock the rows explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `FOR UPDATE OF t2 SKIP LOCKED` is the right approach to prevent race conditions with default [***Read Committed*** transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html).

The added `SKIP LOCKED` also prevents deadlocks. Be aware that competing transactions might each get a partial set from the `SELECT` - whatever it could lock first.

While any transaction is atomic in Postgres, it would not prevent another (also atomic) transaction from selecting (and inserting - or at least trying) the same row, because `SELECT` *without* `FOR UPDATE` does not take an [exclusive lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#locking-rows).

The [Postgres manual about transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html):

> A transaction is said to be *atomic*: from the point of view of other transactions, it either happens completely or not at all.

Related:

- [Postgres UPDATE … LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497)

---

Clarifications:

- An SQL DML command like `INSERT` is always automatically *atomic*, since it cannot run outside a transaction. But you can't say that `INSERT` *is* a transaction. Wrong terminology.
- In Postgres *all* locks are kept until and released at the end of the current transaction.