# Insert new row of data in SQL table if the 2 column values do not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table `interactions` with columns

```
AAId, IDId, S, BasicInfo, DetailedInfo, BN
```

`AAID` and `IDId` are FK to values referencing other tables.

There are around 1540 rows in the `ID` table and around 12 in the `AA` table.

Currently in the `interactions` table there are only around 40 rows for the `AAId value = 12` I want to insert a row for all the missing `IDId` values.

I have searched, but cant find an answer to inserting rows like this. I am not overly confident with SQL, I can do basics but this is a little beyond me.

To clarify, I want to perform a kind of loop where,

```
for each IDId from 1-1540,
   if (the row with AAId = 12 and IDId(current IDId in the loop does not exist)
       insert a new row with,
           AAId = 12,
           IDId = current IDId in the loop,
           S = 1,
           BasicInfo = Unlikely
           DetailedInfo = Unlikely
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can [use data from different tables when inserting data to a table in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898520/postgresql-insert-from-another-table). In your particular example, the following insert should work, as long as you have the correct primary/unique key in `interactions`, which is a combination of `AAId` and `IDId`:

```sql
INSERT INTO interactions (AAId, IDId, S, BasicInfo, DetailedInfo, BN)
SELECT 12, ID.ID, 1, 'Unlikely', 'Unlikely'
FROM ID
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

[`ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) guarantees that the query will not fail when it tries to insert rows that already exist, based on the combination of `AAId` and `IDId`.

If you don't have the correct primary/unique key in `interactions`, you have to filter what IDs to insert manually:

```sql
INSERT INTO interactions (AAId, IDId, S, BasicInfo, DetailedInfo, BN)
SELECT 12, ID.ID, 1, 'Unlikely', 'Unlikely'
FROM ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM interactions AS i
    WHERE i.AAId = 12 AND i.IDId = ID.ID
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am helping a friend out with a project where the developer went AWOL! It looks like they have only set up the interactions table with the ID as the PK and it is linked to lots of other data, so I cant amend the PK to use the AAId and IDId column!

Comment: It's also possible to do it if you don't have the correct key, I've extended my answer with that.